# What are the visa (or any other crucial) requirements of Bhutan for tourists?

Tags: visas, bhutan

I heard that access to Bhutan is quite restricted for all people of outside South-Asian countries? 
Can I have the details on that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhutan couldn't provide much info

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is indeed true. What HaLaBi's answer misses out on - and this is what makes it *expensive* rather than difficult per se - is that the Bhutan government sets a minimum daily tariff that tourists are supposed to spend when booking with a travel agent (and visas can only be obtained once a tour package has been booked with a travel agent).

The details are listed on the [Bhutan tourism website](http://www.tourism.gov.bt/plan-your-trip/travel-requirements).

> The minimum tariff for tourist visiting in a group of 3 persons or
>   more are as follows:
>
> High Season Tariff –  USD$ 250 per person per night for the months of
>   March, April, May, September, October, and November.
>
> Low Season Tariff – USD$200 per person per night for the months of
>   January, February, June, July, August, and December.
>
> The minimum price includes:
>
> ```
> All internal taxes and charges (including the royalty)
> Accommodation
> All Meals
> All travel with a licensed Bhutanese Tour Guide
> All Internal Transport
> Camping Equipment and Haulage for Trekking Tours
> ```
>
> The rates given above are applicable per tourist per night halt in
>   Bhutan. On the day of departure, the ‘local agents’ host obligation
>   shall be limited to breakfast only and any extra requirements shall be
>   payable on actual basis.

Couples or solo travellers have it slightly harder:

> Individual tourists and smaller groups of less than three persons
>   shall be subject to surcharge, o**ver and above the minimum daily rates
>   applicable**, as follows:
>
> Single individual US$ 40 per night Group of 2 persons US$ 30 per
>   person per night
>
> The 10% agency commission payable to agents abroad shall not be
>   deductible from the surcharge

So while the visa is not harder to get, Bhutan controls the influx of tourists using this pricing strategy. It's part of a bigger policy the Bhutan government has on regulating its policies to measure '[Gross National Happiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_national_happiness)' (GNH) rather than [GDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_domestic_product).

Answer (score 6):

Obtaining Bhutanese visa for citizens of other than India, Bangladesh and Maldives seems quite difficult. According to the [official website of Tourism Council of Bhutan](http://www.tourism.gov.bt/plan-your-trip/travel-requirements) you will need to book a tour with a local licensed tour operator directly or through a foreign travel agent which will submit the visa request for you:

> Other than Indian, Bangladeshis and  Maldivian nationals, all visitors to Bhutan require a visa; all visas are issued from Thimphu; visas are only issued to tourists booked with a local licensed tour operator, directly or through a foreign travel agent. Applications for tourist visas are submitted by the tour operator. Visa clearance from Thimphu must be obtained before coming to Bhutan. Visa clearance takes at least 10 days to process. Air tickets to Bhutan cannot be purchased without visa clearance. At your point of entry the visa will be stamped in your passport on payment of US$20, two passport photos will also be required. Visas are issued for a 15day period; extensions can be obtained in Thimphu at a cost of Nu.510.

Comment: It's not difficult, it's just expensive.  Basically anybody with the money can get the visa.

Comment: @jpatokal, true, but making money itself is difficult 

Answer (score 1):

The requirements to get a visa as of 2023-11-24 are stated on https://www.mfa.gov.bt/rbedhaka/visa-for-visiting-bhutan/ and https://visit.doi.gov.bt/help/faq.

One can apply to the visa by oneself via https://visit.doi.gov.bt/. From the [FAQ](https://visit.doi.gov.bt/help/faq):

> Visitors can apply for their visa or permit through this website, or they can engage tourism service providers to process their visa or permit.

From https://www.mfa.gov.bt/rbedhaka/visa-for-visiting-bhutan/:

> What documents do I need in order to apply for a visa?
>
> - A digital copy of your passport.
> - The passport must be valid for six months from the intended date of departure from Bhutan.
> - A recent digital passport size photograph. • Valid travel insurance for the duration of the trip.
>
> Foreigners can stay in Bhutan as a tourist for a maximum of 90 days.

There is fee of 200 USD per day in Bhutan (which is [discounted](https://visit.doi.gov.bt/help/faq) to 100 USD from 01 September 2023 to 31 August 2027).

Follow the links above to read exceptions for some nationalities, ages and non-regular passport types. The requirement stated in this answer are valid for an American or a French citizen aged 18 or older.